# Constructor used instead of or typecast operator

Tags: c++, casting, overloading

I've got the following code

```
    class A {
    private:
            int n;

    public:
            A(int n) : n{n} {}
            A(const A & a) : n{a.n} {}
    };

    class B {
    private:
            int m;
    public:
            B(int n) : m{n} {}
            operator A() const { return A(m); }
            operator int() const { return m; }

    };

    int main(int, char**)
    {
            B b{1};

            (A)b;                // Fails
            static_cast<A>(b);   // Fails
            b.operator A();      // OK
    }
```

This fails with

```
call of overloaded ‘A(B&)’ is ambiguous
```

(gcc, but VC++ and clang seem to handle it the same way)

I'd thought that all three would be the exact same thing. A conversion using B's operator A(). Apparently that's not what's happening. Why?

The problem could easily be solved by making the int() operator explicit, but I'm after an explanation not a solution.

Comment: This is why we now have explicit type cast operators now, e.g. `explicit operator A() const;`. So static_cast and C-style casts are possible, but not implicit casts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`A` can be constructed from `int` or `const A&`, `B` can be converted to both of these, thus these expression are ambigious, because the compiler cannot know whether the two different paths to create some `A` from a `B` lead to identical results.

This is due to `static_cast`s way of determining possible conversion paths:

> If a temporary object of type `new_type` can be declared and initialized with expression, as by `new_type Temp(expression);`, which may involve implicit conversions, a call to the constructor of `new_type` or a call to a user-defined conversion operator, then `static_cast<type>(expression)` computes and returns the value of that temporary object. ([ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast))

Note this part:

> which may involve implicit conversions, a call to the constructor of `new_type` or a call to a user-defined conversion operator

You can implicitly convert `B` to `int`, then construct `A` from `int`.

OR you can convert `B` to `A` as per the conversion operator.

That's where the ambiguity comes from when using a C-style or `static_cast` here.

I would recommend to make the constructor (`A(int)`) `explicit`, not the operators. This is usually the wanted behaviour. This would result in unambigious behaviour for `static_cast<A>(b)`: `operator A()` is used.

Note that `A a = b;` is unambiguous: it will use `operator A()`, since implicit conversions prefer user-defined conversions ([ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast))

Comment: I think the key point is that `(A)b` says "construct an `A`, using `b` to initialize it", it does not say "convert `b` to an `A`". The former means the compiler looks at the constructors of `A` and sees if `b` can be used to call either of them (and finds it can be, by two different routes). The latter would look at the conversion  operators of `B`, and behave as the OP expects, but that's not how the language works.

Comment: Seems like I don't understand the difference between cast and conversion. I though that the cast would force a conversion.

Comment: Not necessarily so. C-style casts are pretty much ambiguous on their own (they evaluate to different C++ casts depending on types and context). Rule of thumb: static_cast<> is the right thing 99% of the time. Then: A type conversion is performed by a cast. Maybe this clears things up for you...

Comment: Also worth noting that `A a = b;` would unambiguously use `operator A()` due to the one-user-defined-conversion rule.

Comment: Not really, I get the problem with C-style casts. But I'd expected static_cast<A> to do a conversion directly to A. Not any suitable conversion that can be used with a constructor.

Comment: "*If a temporary object of type new_type can be declared and initialized with expression, as by ´new_type Temp(expression);´, **which may involve implicit conversions, a call to the constructor of new_type or a call to a user-defined conversion operator**, then static_cast<type>(expression) computes and returns the value of that temporary object.*" http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast ... the bold part is where the ambiguity kicks in. Because you can do a implicit conversion to int and then call constructor, or use user-defined operator.

Comment: @t.c. which is interesting, because that is the clause invokable tests: so a function returning `B` could be passed to a `std` library method that expects an invokable returning `A`, like `async` or `function`.